# Is there such a thing as a universal autorized_keys for 1 ssh_key to work on all accounts on a machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I run a webserver so I'm constantly making new accounts for new domains and logging into them over ssh. Is there a way that instead of pasting my id_dsa.pub file into a new authorized_keys file on each new account, I can put it in one place and automatically be able to login to new accounts? Preferably without doing something like making a user template, because I have other machines I want to add into the master known_hosts at various times, so I wouldn't want to have to go back and update each users known_hosts if it was created using some kind of newuser template.

The servers are running ubuntu 12 lts and 14 lts if this makes a difference, with the default virtualmin setup.

Answer (score 0):

The new user template already exists in `/etc/skel`; copy the file into there and any new users will get a copy of that file in their home directory.